# Resize FXML of a stage component on resizing scene

Tags: javafx, fxml, scene, stage

Please I have this problem i am trying to use

```
scene.getRoot().scaleXProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().divide(dx));
scene.getRoot().scaleYProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().divide(dy));
```

I have tried this code but at the exact size of the Parent, it stop resizing

Comment: Why are you binding the scene's `scaleProperties` with it height and width property?

Comment: I couln'd find the height and width property of the root it'self. So i used the scale property

Comment: Can you add the code for `root`, either FXML or Java code, what-ever you are using?

Comment: i'am trying to insert the code but i don't know how but it is an FXML  file with an anchorpane as root. and components like buttons and textAreas. I tried casting the anchorPane but still same halla(problem)

Comment: Unless you add the fxml or some relative data, I am afraid we can't help.

Comment: <AnchorPane id="Main" fx:id="Mainpane"  prefHeight="490.0"     prefWidth="650.0"fx:controller="application.MainController">
   <children>
      <Button id="close" fx:id="close" layoutX="625.0" layoutY="4.5" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="15.0" />
      <Button id="minimise" fx:id="minimise" layoutX="600" layoutY="4.5"  prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="15.0" />
      <ListView layoutX="14.0" layoutY="144.0" prefHeight="329.0" prefWidth="193.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>

Comment: this is the main public void start(final Stage stage) {
  try {
   
   FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainFXML.fxml")); 
  
   Scene scene = new Scene(root);
   scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
   scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
         stage.setScene(scene);
         resizer.resize(scene);
   
  
   stage.setTitle("Fellowship");
   stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
   stage.show();
   
   // Creating Tray
  
   
  } catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }